# Performing a transaction with Rails ar-octopus gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, transactions, octopus

I couldn't find in ar-octopus (https://github.com/tchandy/octopus) documentation, how can i perform a transaction.

When performing :

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.transaction do
     Octopus.using(:shard, &block)
end
```

the code in the *block* **isn't** running in a transaction.

Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of passing *&block*  you can do the following :

```
Octopus.using(:shard) do
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.transaction do
        block.call   
    end    
end
```

Comment: This appears to just work now with the latest Octopus. Is anyone still needing to explicitly wrap transactions with a `using` block?